# Installing Digits on Ubuntu 16.04 : CUDA 8, CUDNN 5.1, Caffe

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda, caffe

I am pretty new to Caffe, CUDA etc but I have managed to install and test them using a Caffe example targetting the GPU and Keras Example which also focuses on the GPU.  So I am pretty sure all is installed.  I had to build CUDA to install etc. I am using Theano as a back end for Keras.

When I try to install Digits using Pip3 (using Python3) or APT install I get

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.  digits : Depends:
>   python-caffe-nv (>= 0.13) but it is not going to be installed
>             Depends: caffe-nv (>= 0.13) but it is not going to be installed
>             Recommends: torch7-nv but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I know PyCaffe is working?  Sorry if this is a newbie issue

Comment: NVIDIA DIGITS does not support Python 3 as of yet(((. I went through all installation steps at https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/docs/BuildDigits.md
to discover at the end that only Python 2 is supported: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/511. Same environment as yours, Caffe is working, too.

Comment: I know, such a pain in the &*%^, I hope they do fix it, everything I see says move to Python 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)